# GPS periodic location to PHP server from Android app

Tags: android, gps, alarm

How to send periodic location from Android to server? I have tried the following:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, UpdateLocation.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

// Repeat the notification every 15 seconds (15000)
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);             


am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 60 * Interval, pi);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create Service To pass the location to server.

`public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
                super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);`

```
    if(i!=null)
    {
        timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask myTask = new TimerTask(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        //Perform GUI updation work here
                        //Toast work also
                        startTimer();
                    }
                });
            }

        };
        timer.schedule(myTask,10000,60000); \\Time is 60000 milisecond  




    }
    else
    {

        onDestroy();
    }   

       return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;

}
```

`

Starttimer function

`private void startTimer() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

```
//  timer = new Timer();
//  TimerTask myTask = new TimerTask();





            Log.e("LOCATION SERVICE->out","THREAD IS RUN");
             gps = new GpsTracker(SendLocationService.this);
             lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
             if(gps.canGetLocation()){
                        double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                        double longitude = gps.getLongitude();
                        Log.e("LOCATION",latitude+"  "+longitude);
                        if(latitude!=0.0 && longitude!=0.0)
                        {

                        addressText = latitude+","+longitude;

                         // HERE YOU CAN PASS DATA TO SERVER


                        }


                     }


//  
}
```

`